# Computing the expectation from given probabilities.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value

I am given the following. Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of random variables on the probability space $(E, F, P)$. For all $n$ , we have $$ P( X_n = 1/n ) = P(X_n = -1/n) = 1/2 $$
How can I compute the expectation of the random variable $X_n$, given $n$. I get stuck in computing the distribution function. Thanks :)

Comment: The rv takes almost surely two values. Recall that the expectation can be computed as the sum of the values times the probability that it takes such value. You don't really need the distribution function.

Comment: Okay I understand, but can you explain it to me using the definition of the expectation?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you *can* compute the distribution function.  But fortunately you don't need to.

Recall that $$0.5=P(X_n=1/n)=P(A),$$
where
$$A=\{\omega\in X_n:X_n(\omega)=1/n\}$$
Define $B$ similarly (for $-1/n$) so that $0.5=P(B)$.
Set $E_0=E\setminus(A\cup B)$ so that
$$
\mathbb{E}(X_n^+)=\int_{E_0}X_n^+(\omega)dP(\omega)+\int_AX_n^+(\omega)dP(\omega)+\int_BX_n^+(\omega)dP(\omega)
$$
It should be easy to compute this as $0+0.5/n+0=0.5/n$.  The computation for $\mathbb{E}(X_n^-)=0.5/n$ should be just as straightforward.  Hence
$$
\mathbb{E}(X_n)=\mathbb{E}(X_n^+)-\mathbb{E}(X_n^-)=0.5/n-0.5/n=0.
$$

Comment: Thanks, this helps. Can I use this to show that for $Y = \sum_{n \geq 1} X_n$ we have $|Y| < \infty$ a.s. ?